# UIImagePickerController - How do I access the front facing camera by default?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am bringing up the camera with the following code from my ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;     
}

- (IBAction)grabCamera {
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
}
```

How can I make it so the camera by default uses the front camera of the iPhone4 and not the back camera?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront` is not a valid enum for the `sourceType` property.  The `sourceType` property defines whether you're using the camera or the photo library.  You need to set the `cameraDevice` property instead.

### Objective-C

```
self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.imgPicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

### Swift 2

```
imgPicker.sourceType = .Camera
imgPicker.cameraDevice = .Front
```

### Swift 3

```
imgPicker.sourceType = .camera
imgPicker.cameraDevice = .front
```

Comment: @MattyG is it possible to validate what camera is defined from the **UIImagePicker** to control it from one button.
For example:
`if (_pickerController.cameraDevice == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront) {
// change to other camera and vice versa}

Comment: Would you help me at featured question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238781/real-time-face-detection-in-iphone-does-not-work