# Detect faces in real time camera

Tags: swift, camera, real-time, face-detection, avcapturesession

I want to detect all the faces showing in camera using `AVCaptureSession`. I can detect faces in images, but not in a real time camera. I am able to detect a single face only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Face Detection with Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354698/face-detection-with-camera)?